# How to Insert/add the chart in excel using JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, chart.js, office-js

I have added the below snippet to add the table and chart axis in excel. While clicking the Export to Excel button , no excel is downloaded in the browser. I need to draw a chart with the table data. I need a interactive chart in excel with data. I tried with canvas but canvas is exporting as an image. I don't need an image , need a interactive charts based on the table values. I have tried with the below code but its not working. Please suggest the changes or library to insert the chart in excel using JS

```js
async function exportToExcel() {
        const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        const sheetName = "SalesData";
        const wsData = [["Month", "Sales"], ["January", 1000], ["February", 2000]];
        const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(wsData);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws, sheetName);

        // Insert chart
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            const chartRange = sheet.getRange("A1:B3"); // Assuming the data is in range A1:B3

            const chart = sheet.charts.add(
                Excel.ChartType.columnClustered,
                chartRange,
                Excel.ChartSeriesBy.columns
            );

            chart.title.text = "Sales Data";
            chart.legend.position = Excel.ChartLegendPosition.right;

            // Add category axis
            chart.axes.valueAxis.hasTitle = true;
            chart.axes.valueAxis.title.text = "Sales";

            // Add value axis
            chart.axes.categoryAxis.hasTitle = true;
            chart.axes.categoryAxis.title.text = "Month";

            await context.sync();
        });

        // Save Excel file
        const excelData = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
        const blob = new Blob([excelData], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        saveAs(blob, 'sales_data_with_chart.xlsx');
    }
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Export Data to Excel with Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="exportToExcel()">Export to Excel</button>

    <table id="dataTable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Sales</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>January</td>
                <td>1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>February</td>
                <td>2000</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you creating an Excel Add-in? The Office.js library only works in the context of an Excel Add-in.

Comment: @Rich Kirkham I need to insert the chart with the table values dynamically. Is that possible with officeJs

Comment: Yes, but only in the context of an Excel Add-in, not in an ordinary browser window.